# How to Unit Test a class with a nested static class in java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, inner-classes

I have to write a unit test for this class that contains a nested static class. I don't know how to initialize the class variable "mUri" of "_Deferred" to make an assertion that it is not null.

```
public class _Deferred {

    @SerializedName("uri")
    private String mUri;

    public String getUri() {
        return mUri;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private String mUri;

        public _Deferred.Builder withUri(String uri) {
            mUri = uri;
            return this;
        }

        public _Deferred build() {
            _Deferred _Deferred = new _Deferred();
            _Deferred.mUri = mUri;
            return _Deferred;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to initialize "mUri" is appreciated.

What I tried is:

```
@Test
public void testGetUriNotNull() {

    //preparations
    _deferred = new _Deferred();
    _Deferred.Builder builder = new _Deferred.Builder();

}
```

But then i don't know how to set "mUri".

Comment: What do you want to test? That the `mUri` field never is `null`? That `getUri()` never returns `null`? That the builder rejects an attempt to create an instance with a null URI? With the current code, all these tests will fail. The only thing that is currently supported, is that the `mUri` isn't null if the builder is invoked and given a non-null URI.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I Just adapted my question, I saw I posated it with a wrong assertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invoke the `Builder` method 0n `_Deferred` class with desired value for `mUri` field

```
public class StackOverflow {

    @Test
    public void deferredTest(){
        _Deferred deferred = new _Deferred.Builder().withUri("some_uri").build();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(deferred.getUri());
    }
}
```

And test will pass successfully .

[image]

Comment: To reach production-level quality, this "happy-path" test should be augmented with some corner cases: e.g. not calling `withUri()`, calling `withUri(null)`. Of course, expected behaviour for these cases has to be defined first.

Comment: @Mark Happy to help, please consider to approve provided solution as an answer if it satisfied the requirement to improve the community .